# How do I make a django form more aligned

Tags: django-forms

I have a form to edit my Wikipedia entry but since its a django form I am having difficulty designing it
[image: This is how it looks now]

This is the code for the form

```
class EditForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label="Edit Title")
    body = forms.CharField(label="Edit Body", widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={'rows': 1, 'cols': 10}))
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *Django Crispy Forms*, read the documentation on this [page](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)